# which web framework suit for build admin app?

Tags: meteor, web-frameworks

I'm a beginner Codeigniter(PHP) and Javascript programmer. I want to build an app for administration purpose that support desktop and mobile. I think I prefer to make a web. But I confuse about what framework to choose and which one is suit for this purpose. is meteor suit for this purpose?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It completely depends on what Scenario you have, to create Admin App on web.

You can use below theme to make a Admin Panel.

To View live theme : [Click Here](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html)

To Download the theme : [Download Here](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/releases)

Now comming to the point, If you need a real time Web Application to create a Admin App in *very less time, still secure, robust, much better than REST API, massive read-writes to DB*, then Meteor 1.5.2 is really heaven (also keep in mind how complex is your database going to be, because Meteor comes with MongoDB inbuilt support and MongoDB does not support mapping constraints. You may use "Linking". Though Meteor now supports other databases like 'postgres' and 'mysql', you may need to study how to merge them.[Click Here](https://meteor-postgres.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

> Also keep in mind how many concurrent users are going to use your application if built with meteor. If you that is huge number you might be interested in hosting your application to Cheap and yet powerful Virtual Private Server [VPS](https://www.hostitsmart.com/vps-hosting)

If you do not have a real time requirement then Meteor is overkill and not really required, definitely there are other frameworks available as in PHP you may use Yii2 PHP Framework which is very mature framework or you may use Laravel 5.x. Code Igniter is little Immature and lacks many advanced feature that can make application real secure and developed fast.

The reason to find why you may use Meteor : [Click Here](https://wiki.dandascalescu.com/essays/why_meteor)

Comment: thx you give me very complete explanation. I'm very appreciate it

Comment: It is my pleasure to help you and guide you. 3 years back I was at your stage, so learn and earn always :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Nicotine Framework](https://nicotine-framework.com).

It contains many features, such as built in support for Admin, API requests and CLI scripts.
It also come with an admin prototype interface for users and roles.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)